# Correct wording for quiz questions

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I am developing a geography quiz game but am unsure about the wording of some quiz questions:

1. **To which geographical region do these countries belong?**
   (*here I am not sure if I should use "to" at the end of the question*)
2. **Which country or territory belonging to this country was part of this empire?** (*I am not sure if I should encapsulate between commas this part: "or territory belonging to this country"*)
3. **Which countries or territories belonging to these countries were part of this empire?**
   (*Same as above*)
4. **To which empire did these countries or territories belonging to these countries belong?**
   (*Same as above*)

Please feel free to suggest any reformulations of the questions.

Comment: Replace ***countries or territories belonging to these countries*** by ***countries or territories thereof*** (same principle for the corresponding *singular* reference ***country or territory thereof***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers There being no territories among the multiple choice answers, that formulation wouldn't be logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 & 4. The word *to* shouldn't be repeated. There are two correct options:

> 1a To which geographical region do these countries belong?
> 1b Which geographical region do these countries belong to?

For 2, 3, and 4, I suggest
**which countries or territories**
to replace
*which countries or territories belonging to these countries*

Since you are asking *which countries*, there's no established referent yet for *these countries*. If you just say *which countries or territories*, the question will be more understandable.

You have added that the answer consists only of countries; that being so, maybe you could use,
**Which countries were part of this empire, or have territories that were?**
Since only countries are included in the answer, the question should not ask *which countries or territories*, however you qualify *territories*.

There is also a question of whether the countries and any putative territories were contemporaneous. I suggest this as an alternative formulation that may cover all possibilities:

> **Which present-day countries were partly or entirely part of the British Empire?**

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Jack O'Flaherty. Regarding your suggestion to replace "which countries or territories belonging to these countries" with "which countries or territories". 
In my case the question will look like this: 

Which countries or territories belonging to these countries were part of this empire?
Empire: British Empire
Options: China, India, Vietnam.

As you can see I can't use "which countries or territories" because I will only have countries as valid options. This is why I used "territories belonging to these countries"

Comment: @hhh3112 Maybe, *Which countries were part of this empire, or have territories that were?* Since only countries are included in the answer, the question should not ask *which countries or territories*, however you qualify *territories*.

Comment: Thanks! I like this word choice: Which present-day countries were partly or entirely part of the British Empire?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put *"to"* at either end of the question with the same meaning, but  probably at the end is best.
2. I suggest the **belonging to this country** should be enclosed in commas.

> Which country or territory, belonging to this country, was part of this empire?

3. Similarly

> Which countries or territories, belonging to these countries, were part of this empire?

4. This is not a good way of asking the question, it's just not easily and elegantly expressed [thanks FumbleFingers for this edit]. It would never be used by a native English speaker.

From question 2 I understand that at some time country (or territory) A belonged to country B and at some other time A belonged to empire C. Similarly for question 3 two or  more countries were owned by two or more other countries that at some other time they belonged to an empire.
You may wish to rephrase question 2 to read

> Which country or territory belonging to country B later belonged to empire C?

If ownership changed in the opposite chronological order you can say "... earlier belonged to empire C". Question 3 can be similarly re-written.

Comment: re point #4 - it *does* "make sense" as a concept. It's just not easily and elegantly expressed in English. But per my comment above, ***countries or territories thereof*** would pretty much pass muster - *faute de mieux* and all that. (A moot point whether that should be explicitly identified as ***present-day** territories,* though, in order to truly make sense! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for that, I agree. I've updated my answer to reflect your  observation.